# PHP pagination problem

Tags: php, pagination

So for some reason I am trying to figure out why my pagination isnt working properly. I get it to move from page 1 to 2 but it wont go to page 3 for some reason. I checked to see if the query from the DB was correct and it was so not sure where I am going wrong.

```
$per_page = '4';

$tenure_sql =  'SELECT COUNT(id) as count
                FROM people.bywu
                WHERE type <> 0
                AND status = "approved"';

$tenure_query = mysql_query( $tenure_sql, DB );

$tenure_count = mysql_fetch_object( $tenure_query );
$tenure_count = $tenure_count -> count;
$tenure_pages = ceil( $tenure_count / $per_page );

<div class="pagination" id="tenure_pages">
<a href="" class="lt grayed">&lt;</a>
Stories <span id="tenure_low" class="current_low"><?= $tenure_count ? '1':'0' ?></span>-<span id="tenure_high" class="current_high"><?= $tenure_count > 4 ? $per_page : $tenure_count ?></span> of <span class="total"><?= $tenure_count ?></span>
<a href="" class="gt<?= $tenure_count < 5 ? ' grayed':'' ?>">&gt;</a>
<span class="pages" style="display:none;"><?= $tenure_pages ?></span>
<?
    for( $i = 1; $i < $tenure_pages + 1; $i++ )
    {
    echo '<a href="">' . $i . '</a> ';
    } // for
?>
```

Comment: "Not working properly" is not a good error description. What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: I get it to navigate to the 2nd page which shows 4 articles then when I try to go to page 3 which is 9-12 the > just doesnt move to the next page just does nothing.

Comment: The what doesn't move to the next page?  All I see is a > sign.

Comment: Just as a recommendation: In the SQL command use LIMIT for your pagination. You will generate a lot less IO: http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: I think you could start by reordering your code, not only for us to understand it more quickly, but for you to do code more robust.

Comment: I also see that you don't include the SQL statement where you actually make the query for the pagination itself. The SQL we are viewing just gets the amount of rows you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapped away from kohana pagination class, i think you will find it useful if you know any basics about php classes.

Usage :

```
$pager = Pagination::factory(array('current_page' => $_GET['page'], 'total_items' => $total_items, 'items_per_page' => 20));

if ($pager->next_page) { /* etc.......*/ }

<?php
class Pagination {


    protected $config = array(
            'current_page'      => 1,
        'total_items'       => 0,
        'items_per_page'    => 10
    );

    // Current page number
    protected $current_page;

    // Total item count
    protected $total_items;

    // How many items to show per page
    protected $items_per_page;

    // Total page count
    protected $total_pages;

    // Item offset for the first item displayed on the current page
    protected $current_first_item;

    // Item offset for the last item displayed on the current page
    protected $current_last_item;

    // Previous page number; FALSE if the current page is the first one
    protected $previous_page;

    // Next page number; FALSE if the current page is the last one
    protected $next_page;

    // First page number; FALSE if the current page is the first one
    protected $first_page;

    // Last page number; FALSE if the current page is the last one
    protected $last_page;

    // Query offset
    protected $offset;

    /**
     * Creates a new Pagination object.
     *
     * @param   array  configuration
     * @return  Pagination
     */
    public static function factory(array $config = array())
    {
        return new Pagination($config);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Pagination object.
     *
     * @param   array  configuration
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {


        // Pagination setup
        $this->setup($config);

    }



    /**
     * Loads configuration settings into the object and (re)calculates pagination if needed.
     * Allows you to update config settings after a Pagination object has been constructed.
     *
     * @param   array   configuration
     * @return  object  Pagination
     */
    public function setup(array $config = array())
    {


        // Only (re)calculate pagination when needed
        if ($this->current_page === NULL
            OR isset($config['current_page'])
            OR isset($config['total_items'])
            OR isset($config['items_per_page']))
        {

            // Calculate and clean all pagination variables
            $this->current_page = (int) $this->config['current_page'];
            $this->total_items        = (int) max(0, $this->config['total_items']);
            $this->items_per_page     = (int) max(1, $this->config['items_per_page']);
            $this->total_pages        = (int) ceil($this->total_items / $this->items_per_page);
            $this->current_page       = (int) min(max(1, $this->current_page), max(1, $this->total_pages));
            $this->current_first_item = (int) min((($this->current_page - 1) * $this->items_per_page) + 1, $this->total_items);
            $this->current_last_item  = (int) min($this->current_first_item + $this->items_per_page - 1, $this->total_items);
            $this->previous_page      = ($this->current_page > 1) ? $this->current_page - 1 : FALSE;
            $this->next_page          = ($this->current_page < $this->total_pages) ? $this->current_page + 1 : FALSE;
            $this->first_page         = ($this->current_page === 1) ? FALSE : 1;
            $this->last_page          = ($this->current_page >= $this->total_pages) ? FALSE : $this->total_pages;
            $this->offset             = (int) (($this->current_page - 1) * $this->items_per_page);
        }

        // Chainable method
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a Pagination property.
     *
     * @param   string  property name
     * @return  mixed   Pagination property; NULL if not found
     */
    public function __get($key)
    {
        return isset($this->$key) ? $this->$key : NULL;
    }

    /**
     * Updates a single config setting, and recalculates pagination if needed.
     *
     * @param   string  config key
     * @param   mixed   config value
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->setup(array($key => $value));
    }

} // End Pagination

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `count()` you get from the database is `9` or larger, you'd never see a `3`.

```
   ceil(0/4) -> 0
   ...
   ceil(8/4) -> 2
   ceil(9/4) -> 3
```

So... how many articles are there in the database that match the conditions in your query?

---

You don't show how you're passing around the "current page" count in your code, so how does the code know which page you're on at the moment?

```
$total_pages = 8;
$current_page = $_GET['curPage'];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
   $class = ($i == $current_page) ? ' class="current"' : '';
   echo <<<EOL
<a href="page.php?curPage=$i"$class>$i</a>

EOL;
}
```

Comment: I get a result of 21 rows that comeback from the DB